# unable to load a simple csv in networkx in Python

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I am a complete noobie in Python, and I would like to study a dataset using the networkx package. I do not understand what is wrong here:

I have a csv which looks like this (extract):

```
['152027', '-6167']
['152027', '-4982']
['152027', '-3810']
['152027', '-2288']
['152027', '-1253']
['152100', '-152100']
['152100', '-86127']
```

lets call this .csv file `nodes`. Numbers heres have no particular meanings. They are just anonymised names: so 152027 is a person that is connected to individual -6167, individual -4982, etc.

I use the following code in Python

```
import csv
import networkx as nx

file = csv.reader(open('nodes', 'rb'), delimiter=',')

G=nx.read_edgelist(file, delimiter=',',nodetype=float,encoding='utf-8')
G.number_of_nodes()
```

and I get the sad `Out[71]: 0`
I do not understand what is wrong here.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Is that really what your "csv file" looks like, or is that what the lists you get when you iterate over your `csv.reader` look like?

Comment: Well, the first issue is that read_edgelist is expecting a file object and you are passing it a csv.reader object

Comment: @DSM this is what I get when I type `for row in file:print row`

Comment: @Noobie: okay, that's fine then.  Just wanted to make sure there weren't square brackets in the file itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nx.read_edgelist` expects the first variable to be a file handle or filename string, not a `csv.reader` object.

Don't use `csv` at all; try just

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('nodes', delimiter=',', nodetype=int, encoding="utf-8")
```

**Edit:** if you need to skip a header line, you could do

```
with open('nodes', 'rb') as inf:
    next(inf, '')   # skip a line
    G = nx.read_edgelist(inf, delimiter=',', nodetype=int, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks! Great! But what I should have done if my csv contained column `headers` then?

Answer (score 0):

file is a python keyword. Try naming the variable something else like csvfile.